# React Cookie + ReactJS: How to set expiration time for a cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, token, reactjs

In my ReactJS project, currently I am saving the cookie like `cookie.save('token', received_token, { path: '/'} );` and retrieving it from the local storage like so: `cookie.load('token');`.

So I was wondering, is a way to set expiration time when `.save()` the token received, and once expired, automatically have it remove itself from the local storage?

Thank you and will accept the answer with vote up.

Answer (score 21):

You can pass `maxAge` or `expires` in options as 3rd parameter in `cookie.save` function

Syntax:

```
reactCookie.save(name, val, [opt])
```

Example:

```js
// maxAge Example
reactCookie.save("token", "token-value", {
   maxAge: 3600 // Will expire after 1hr (value is in number of sec.)
});

// Expires Example
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);

reactCookie.save("token", "token-value", {
   expires: tomorrow // Will expire after 24hr from setting (value is in Date object)
});
```

Documentation: https://github.com/eXon/react-cookie#reactcookiesetrawcookiecookies

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, a few questions if you don't mind. Do I declare it like `reactCookie.save(name, val, [expires: 5000])`? Could you clarify when to use one over the other, between `maxAge` and `expires`? Read the documentation but can't seem to tell the difference. Also, when it `expires`, does it automatically remove the token itself from the local storage? Thank you for the response!

Comment: @Walter I added the example in answer only and also added the diff between both the options

Comment: @Walter Local Storage doesn't expire its upto user to handle when to delete.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clarification. So what happens after the token expires? How can I get it to remove itself from the local storage when it does?

Comment: in case of local storage you just set value of that local storage to `null` or `undefined` to reset or expire. and in case of cookie you should get `undefined` if you try to access expired cookie

Comment: Is there a way to check if the cookie expired via `react-cookie`?

Comment: Just do .load for that cookie and if it returns undefined then its expired

Comment: Sorry but could you show quick as an example? Like `if(cookie.load('token')){ //remove the token}`?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you had the chance to see my previous comment.

Comment: What will happen if today is last day of month? today.getDate()+1 may go beyond total number of days in a month.

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan it will return the first day of the next month